# Failed to generate output. Reason: Cannot navigate to invalid URL (Convert xaringan html or rmd file into pdf)

Tags: r-markdown, xaringan

I am trying to convert xaringan slide to pdf file using the following code found in
[this page](https://github.com/yihui/xaringan/issues/168)

````
---
title: "Lecture"
subtitle: "subtitle"
author: "Instructor"
institute: "University"
output: 
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    css: [default, metropolis, metropolis-fonts, "styles.css"]
    lib_dir: libs
    seal: false
    nature:
      highlightStyle: arta
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
      titleSlideClass: [top, left]
 
---
class: title-slide, top, left, inverse
background-image: url(aaa.jpeg)
background-size: cover

# *`r rmarkdown::metadata$title`*
## *`r rmarkdown::metadata$subtitle`*
### `r rmarkdown::metadata$author`
### `r rmarkdown::metadata$institute`
### `r rmarkdown::metadata$date`
### `r Sys.Date()`

```{css, echo=FALSE}
<style>
.remark-slide-content.hljs-default {
  border-top: 40px solid #23373B;
}

.remark-slide-content > h1 {
  font-size: 35px;
  margin-top: -85px;
}
```
---

# Why people are constantly switching?

---

remotes::install_github('rstudio/pagedown')
pagedown::chrome_print('lecture_1.html')

```
````

But I got the following error message:

> Error in force(expr) :
> Failed to generate output. Reason: Cannot navigate to invalid URL

My question is how to fix the issue and where is the more proper location of my command (can I put the code on the slide or should I put it on a separate window panel in Rstudio)?

Comment: Add a code of your slide

Comment: I just updated my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run this code `pagedown::chrome_print('lecture_1.html')` from console (assuming your html file is in your working directory).

Also Note that here you are rendering the html output made from the r-markdown source file. But you can use your r-markdown file as input to `chrome_print` like this,

```
pagedown::chrome_print("lecture_1.Rmd")
```

Comment: The thing is I need to properly add main directory and subdirectories before the file name. Thanks!